# How to find files modified on a specific day/month date (but with no specific year)

Tags: rhel

I'm looking for a find cmd argument to find every files modified in a specific day/month regardless of the year.
For example, I would like to put in a file each file modified during any of 20th August

I've tried to do a `find (my path/files parameters) -newert 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM'` by replacing YYYY with **** (for example ... I tried many bad stuffs)

Can anyone help me ? :)

Thanks !

Comment: `find` may need external help on this. You could add `-exec stat -t --printf='%y %n\n' {} '+'`, pipe that to an `awk` that selects for `-08-20` in field 1, and then strips off 3 fields of timestamp. Also change that `\n` to `\0` and use `RS='\0'` in awk to deal with newlines in filenames.